# Merge two streams with flatMapLatest

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive

having a problem with combining to observables in flatMapLatest

**Logic**: on every activity next event, I want to combine it together with the next `getCurrentLocation` event, which happens after activityEvent was triggered, join them together in a tuple and then do something with it.

Currently, it is like this

```
ActivitiesController
    .start()
    .flatMapLatest { activity in 
        LocationController.shared.getCurrentLocation().map { ($0, activity) }
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { (activity, currentLocation in
        print("")
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Location code:

```
func getCurrentLocation() -> Observable<CLLocation> {
    self.requestLocationUseAuthorizationIfNotDetermined(for: .always)
    self.locationManager.requestLocation()
    return self.publishSubject.take(1) // take next object from the publish subject (only one)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last, location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 else {
        return
    }
    self.publishSubject.onNext(location)
}
```

Since we know that `requestLocation()` triggers didUpdateLocations, we were thinking the logic should work, but it doesn't

the result is locationManager not always updating and returning old values instead of new ones

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Try to print out the locations array and check its content.
Maybe the location changes are not enough to be detected.
I don't know how publishSubject.take() works, but it seems it is returned before requestLocation finish. Is this the behaviour you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `withLatestFrom` instead of `flatMapLatest`.

```
LocationController.shared.getCurrentLocation().withLatestFrom(activityEvent) {
    // in here $0 will refer to the current location that was just emitted and
    // $1 will refer to the last activityEvent that was emitted.
    return ($0, $1)
}
```